# Alternative to eval for assigning a model attribute from a string

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm looking for a way to assign a model attribute from a string. This is within a concern shared across multiple models with different attributes, so I can't just hard code the attribute names.

I'm having no problem retrieving attributes using a string with 'send':

```
self.send("#{attribute_name}")
```

But I'm having difficulty assigning the attribute from a string. E.g

```
self."attribute_name" = "<user input>"
```

The dreaded eval function does what I need, but it is clearly terrible unsafe:

```
eval("self.#{attribute_name} = '<user input>'")
```

Is there a function I am missing that can achieve this without eval? Or is my approach all wrong and I should do back to the drawing board? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the the attribute has a public setter method, this works:

```
class X
  attr_accessor :foo

  def dynamic_set(attr_name, value)
    public_send("#{attr_name}=", value)
  end
end

x = X.new
x.dynamic_set("foo", "bar")
p x.foo
# => "bar"
```

Comment: Beware that `public_send` will raise an exception if the method isn't present or not public.

Comment: Just saw your edit - this looks like a great implementation, thanks again! I'll mark this as the answer when it lets me (7 minutes apparently).

Answer (score 1):

You should save them as instance variables.

To get:

```
instance_variable_get("@#{attribute_name}")
```

To set:

```
instance_variable_set("@#{attribute_name}", user_input)
```

Comment: Isn't this unwise given that the user can set an arbitrary instance variable in this way? So you could attack the system by setting a large amount of instance variables to very large string values?

Comment: @Jesper The OP wrote "I can't just hard code the attribute names." How is it possible to do that without breaking this requirement?

Comment: True, I missed that. But it seems the OP didn't quite mean what he or she wrote since my answer got accepted.

Comment: What is the advantage of saving them as instance variables? Jespers solution worked great for my needs, even if my question was worded badly :)

Comment: @RichardAE You would have to define each pairs of setter/getter separately in order to make that work. The answer here works on the fly. If you are not saving them as instance variables, then where are you saving them?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just wanted to assign self.attribute_name to the first value in the hash I had processed before it - it's being used in a before_save callback, so after the before save callback has assigned the attribute it's saved as part of the standard save method.